# aps-entitlement missing with ionic package build

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am building ios application using Ionic version 3 and want to implement Push Notification feature on my ios application.

I created development security profile and prepared all the required certificates and provisioning profile.

Using the .ipa file generated from ionic package build i tried registering to push notification.
But whenever it tries to register to push notification I always get warning about aps-entitlement missing etc.

All of the solution that I have found requires me to build using XCode and add the aps-entitlement from Capabilities tab.

My question is, how to add aps-entitlement using ionic package build?